# Which payment gateway should I use for my app (flutter developed)? I'm currently using Firebase as Backend, and flutter for coding

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, e-commerce

I'm creating an app that works like a food delivery app. Until now all the functionalities are build and working, but to end the project I need to implement the "e-commerce" side. My issue here is what to do since I have a flutter coded application and Firebase as my Backend.

I have already tried Stripe, but it doesn't have support in my country. Now I'm trying with Square, but since it has no integration with Firebase, I would end up with 2 Servers (1 for the payment and 1 for the other stuff), because I would probably have to create a NodeJS server or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Please go and check for `Paystack`. They have also packages for flutter so you can choose according to your level of expertise